# How do I tell VS code what toolchain I want to use?

Tags: rust, visual-studio-code

After installing extensions for Rust, I get this error:

> To properly function, the extension needs to know what toolchain you
>   want to use.

Comment: Did you install `rustup`?

Comment: once you installed rustup, just close the error and it will propose you to choose from one of the available toolchains.

Answer (score 89):

Press **Close** to select toolchain :)

Answer (score 7):

The extension will provide a prompt after you close that prompt, which allows you to select the toolchain you want. You can see the toolchain that you selected in your preferences file.

Answer (score 4):

As the message says, you must choose a toolchain ([documentation here](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/rustup.rs)):

```
$ rustup default stable
```

for the stable Rust, or

```
$ rustup default nightly
```

for the newest development version.

If you only want to play with Rust, I advise you to use nightly Rust because there are more new things in it.

Comment: I've set rustup default stable-gnu, but I still see the popup message.

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your configuration with toolchain you want to use to enforce it in VS Code:

```
"rust.rustup": {
    "toolchain": "stable-x86_64-apple-darwin"
  }
```